# How can start a DAG in random time

Tags: random, dynamic, scheduler, airflow

I have a DAG that triggered by airflow scheduler and runs at 1 min passed midnight every day. I want to change the start time every day to be dynamic, one day to start at 1:00 am , the next day at 00:16 and etc. Is there any configuration in airflow to do this? If not what can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know airflow doesnt support this. But you can do a workaround. You can schedule a dag to run midnight every day, and this dag change the start date of the other dag.

Comment: Great! Just set the response to correct for help other users.